# How to get Preferences value from another page without reloading the page in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have

1. Page1.xaml

   ```
   <Label x:Name="getPreferences" />
   <Button x:Name="one" Clicked="one_Clicked"/>
   ```
2. Page1.xaml.cs

   ```
   public Page1()
   {
       string getpre = Preferences.Get("PreOne", "defaultpre");
       getPreferences.Text = getpre;
   }
   private async void one_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Popup());
   }
   ```
3. Popup.xaml (using Rg Popup)

   ```
   <popup:PopupPage
     ....
     <StackLayout x:Name="ss">
                    <Image Source="img"/>
                    <Label Text="Testtttt" />
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ss_Tapped" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
   </popup:PopupPage>
   ```
4. Popup.xaml.cs

   ```
   private void ss_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string setone = "01";
      Preferences.Set("PreOne", setone);
   }
   ```

How can I get the value of `Preferences` to assign to the Label `getPreferences` without me having to reload the page Page1. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `PopupNavigation` has a `Popped` event you can subscribe to refresh your data when the popup is dismissed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences Essential package have no event for changing preferences , so you have to get your value every time you change it . i suggest you to create your own event in popup and fire it when your value changed

1.PopUp.xaml.cs

```
    public event EventHandler PreOneChanged; 
    private void ss_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string setone = "01";
        Preferences.Set("PreOne", setone);
        PreOneChanged?.Invoke(setone,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

2.Page1.xaml.cs

```
    public Page1()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        string getpre = Preferences.Get("PreOne", "defaultpre");
        getPreferences.Text = getpre;
    }
    private async void one_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var popUp = new Popup();
        popUp.PreOneChanged += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            Init();
        };
        PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popUp);

    }
```

Now when your value changed in PopUp your event call and in page will change that

Answer (score 0):

Try using ViewModels and bindings so that all these things happen automatically